# How to pass header of csv in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I want to create a csv file in a loop. But when I do so, it also writes header part also. How can I write the header part only for a time?

```
fieldnames=['numbers']
for i in range(0,100):
    with open('numbers.csv','a',newline='') as csvfile:
        writer=csv.Dictwriter(csvfile,fieldnames=fieldnames,lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'numbers':i})
```

Comment: Do a condition where you check the `i` variable and only write the header when it's equal to `0`?

Comment: @techouse well, technically it _would_ work, but it has a bit of a Rube Goldberg machine smell...

Comment: I agree, but it is the most simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply: move this part out of the loop (seems obvious...). You DONT want to reopen the file in each iteration anyway (opening a file - and closing it FWIW - is far from free):

```
fieldnames=['numbers']
with open('numbers.csv','a',newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.Dictwriter(csvfile,fieldnames=fieldnames,lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writeheader()
    for i in range(100):
        writer.writerow({'numbers':i})
```